# response status code 200 but cors error in react js axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors

I am trying to hit a open source API from https://citizenatlas.dc.gov/newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2
using axios.
My code is:

```
let fetchDCWardUrl = 'https://citizenatlas.dc.gov/newwebservices/locationverifier.asmx/findLocation2?str=2%252015th%2520St%2520NW,%2520Washington,%2520DC%252020024,%2520USA&f=json';

await axios.get(fetchDCWardUrl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

And I am getting:
[image]
[image]
When I hit the same URL from the postman or directly hit the browser URL bar, I get a response without any error. I also tried using the post method, tried js fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cors must be enabled on server-side. For development purposes you can use [react proxy settins](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) but on production server you must correctly setup your server to create proxy for this request

Comment: `setup your server to create proxy for this request` is this supposed to be done for my frontend hosted server?

Comment: This is how i would do it... it depens on which server technology are you using. In my case i would do it somehow in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I think the website must allow the request from javascript. Thats a server side thing. You shouldn't be able to send request to the backend without proof that you are the "real" frontend it belongs to. Its a security feature from your browser. If you open this normaly the browser doesn't catch that...

To fix that you could write your own backend which catches the request and sends the content to your frontend and then set the cors there.

Comment: So if the same API is hit from the live server, will it possibly work? There is also a website that hits API from same server, but its able to fetch the data. URL is: https://planning.dc.gov/whatsmyward

Comment: Yea sure its a browser security feature, as you mentioned it worked if you entered the url normaly into your browser, if you make your backend, this backend sends a call as a normal browser and then set the right cors there it will perfectly work.